# UILabel Text value inside UITableViewCell Swaps

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

`UILabel` Text value inside `UITableViewCell` is getting Swapped each time i load.as my `cell height` is 140 `cell.TextLabel.text` is not able to set `frame` and to make it display at centre.But i need TitleText to be displayed at Beginning of the cell.so, i used `UILabel` to display as i need.But each time while i load cell its displaying wrong title for those cell.But when i log that array it Logs correctly and if i check with `cell.TextLabel.text` it displays correctly.but not in `UILabel`.Confused lot.Not able to trace where i have gone wrong.Thanks in Advance. 
Below is My Code.

`

```
 -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return 140;
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    UILabel *Title;
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        Title = [[UILabel alloc]init ];
        Title.frame =CGRectMake(20, 18, 152, 23);
        [Title sizeToFit];
    }
    NSMutableArray *contentArray = [sectionDict valueForKey:[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
    NSLog(@"content %@",contentArray);
    Title.text = [contentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell addSubview:Title];
    UIImageView *seaImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"PacificOcean.png" ]];
    seaImage.frame = CGRectMake(20, 60, 280, 80);
    [cell addSubview:seaImage];
    return cell;
}
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add Your subviews **Label** and the **image** to cell  in `cell == nil` block set tag for each subview. Access your subviews outside the block by tag. I hope it is helpful to you.

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
  UILabel *Title = [[UILabel alloc]init ];
           Title.tag = 1000;
           Title.frame =CGRectMake(20, 18, 152, 23);
          [Title sizeToFit];
  [cell.contentView addSubview:Title];

 UIImageView *seaImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"PacificOcean.png" ]];
          seaImage.frame = CGRectMake(20, 60, 280, 80);
[cell.contentView addSubview:seaImage];
}
  NSMutableArray *contentArray = [sectionDict valueForKey:[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
  UILabel *Title = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1000];
  Title.text = [contentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  return cell;
```

Change your code like this..

Comment: @TamilKing - sorry i cant get you

Comment: @user1980105@now you got idea how to add subviews in cell

Comment: @TamilKing,check my answer

Comment: @GreyCode: Try this code I hope it will works perfect. Otherwise comment what error  are you got..

Comment: @TamilKing - title label is not displaying.may be because of frame issue.if i set frame for 2nd title it loads.wow its working correctly.thanks man

Comment: @GreyCode:My pleasure.

Answer (score 2):

use your code like this

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
UILabel *Title;
if (cell == nil) {
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
Title = [[UILabel alloc]init ];
Title.frame =CGRectMake(20, 18, 152, 23);
[Title sizeToFit];
[cell.contentView addSubview: Title];

UIImageView *seaImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"PacificOcean.png" ]];
seaImage.frame = CGRectMake(20, 60, 280, 80);
[cell.contentView addSubview: seaImage];
}
NSMutableArray *contentArray = [sectionDict valueForKey:[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
NSLog(@"content %@",contentArray);
Title.text = [contentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
}
```

Comment: title label is missing in TableCell

Comment: use NSLog (@"%@",[contentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row])

Comment: it is logging that array values.but not available in cell

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is a typo on your part but `cell.TextLabel.text` is a NSString so you can not set frame to that but `cell.TextLabel.frame` should work. Another problem you have in the approach you are using is that `UILabel *Title;` is declared outside if statement then operated on after if statement ends where it will be `nil` if you successfully dequeue a cell. And since objective-C is so nice to you it will not complain when you pass messages to `nil`. If you want to use this approve you need to also add the label to your cell in the if statement with maybe a tag and then get the same label when you want to set the frame. This is the same with your `seaImage` you should not add a new one each time you provide a cell.

Comment: sorry by mistaken i mentioned as cell.TextLabel.text for frame.and in cell.TextLabel.frame only it was not able to set position by frame.

Comment: I don't understand. Way can't you do 'cellTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,w,h)'. Do you get a error message or what?

Comment: sorry.setting frame for default textLabel in cell wont work.as far as i know. please try it once on yourself and let me know if it works.Thanks

Comment: Y position in `textLabel frame` is not working.always in middle of cell.